# How to write a test that uses subdomains in play?

Tags: scala, junit, playframework

I have a play application that uses subdomains.

Currently I have dns setup on my laptop so I can browse URLS locally like:

subdomain1.myappurl.com:9000/
subdomain2.myappurl.com:9000/

(I have myappurl pointing to 127.0.0.1).

I want to create a test now that uses these URLS (I want to provide the URL)

**How can I do this with FakeRequest?**

Also, what is FakeRequest, is it a headless browser?  I ideally want to create a integration test (but not testing the UI side of things) to make sure data is correctly written to the database when I login/logout etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit**: In light of the OP's comments, there is a way to override the host name in the `FakeRequest`, by adding it as a header. It appears that `request.host` is actually set in the `Request` trait where it's just derived from the headers.

```
import play.api.http.HeaderNames
FakeRequest(GET, "/something").withHeaders(HeaderNames.HOST -> "sub.domain.com")
```

---

The `FakeRequest is just passed through the router of the`FakeApplication`(if using the`route`helper), and what you get is the`Result` from the controller function. No headless browser involved here.

What *will* use a headless browser is the [WithBrowser](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.test.WithBrowser) helper.

```
"go to the right url" in new WithBrowser(webDriver = WebDriverFactory(HTMLUNIT)) {
      browser.goTo("google.com")
      browser.pageSource must not contain("Bing")
      // Do other things ...
}
```

`WithBrowser` is kind of overkill for testing whether or not data has been saved.

Comment: clients have their own subdomain, so it is a crucial part of my app testing.

Comment: Routing does not look at subdomains, in my custom action I look at the request object to get the subdomain.

Comment: Wow, brillian thanks a bundle.  BTW, where can I see a list of all of these methods like:  contentType, contentAsString, redirectToLocation etc.

Comment: Play API Docs: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.test.Helpers$  `FakeRequest` is located in that same package, though I had to did a little into the source to see how it was setting its headers.